# php node.js redis session share Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, session, redis

i just use php and node.js and after search i found only way for Authentication with user

so first thing i change my php session save bath to redis

and this is my code for insert session

> session_name("userID");
>
> session_start();
>
> $_SESSION["username"] = "hello world";

this is image for redis and its show the session

[image]
and here is my my browser cookie

[image]

i just want to Authentication  the session on node.js so if user login in php ...
node.js send data to user else refuse user ... or send data from mysql by node.js

so here i build node.js server

[image]

every thing its work good i require socket on client and i send data to server ..

every time user send value by socket i want to Authentication the user if user login php (session found in redis) send data to user else ... send u must login first

my problem on how to check if the session in redis by node.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to query your redis db for the session information, with something like given below

```
//user.js
```

Add user and its session in appsession hash map in redis

```
exports.addUserSession = function (redisClient,userId,sessionId,callback){

      redisClient.hset('appsession',sessionId,userId,function(err,response){
           callback(err,response);
      });
};


exports.validateUserSession = function (redisClient,userId,sessionId,callback){
    redisClient.hget('appsession',sessionId,function(err,response){
            if(response==userId)
            {
                callback(err,true);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(err,false);
            }
    });
};
```

you can then use the same method in your code to check whether user session is available or not. E.g

```
var session = require(./user.js );
socket.on("selector", function( data) { 
        sessionID = data.handshake.session;
        USERNAME = socket.username;
        session.validateUserSession(redisClient,USERNAME,sessionID,function(err,response){
            // Do other processing if session is valiated
       }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sessionID = data.handshake.session;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined

Comment: You have used the data.handshake.session in your code. You need to check the session id in your stored session. One you get the sessionId you can use the code given.

Comment: its give me error this the client   
socket.emit("selector", "give me some data");

and on server   

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {  
 


socket.on("selector", function(data) {   
 
        sessionID = data.handshake.session;   
        USERNAME = socket.username;   
        session.validateUserSession(redisClient,USERNAME,sessionID,function(err,response){   
            // Do other processing if session is valiated   
       });   
});   
 

 


 
 
 });  

sessionID = data.handshake.session;  
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined –

Comment: console.log(data);  

give me some data == the message i sent it to server

Comment: Well you need to first establish the socket connection. You need to check your code for that. I have provided you the illustration of how to store the data inside redis session and how to check the session details in redis for the same. You need to do some R&D for that , Although I can provide you the code